# How to use b-pagination api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
layoutchange() {

  this.layout = !this.layout;

  if (this.layout === true) {

    this.perPage = this.layout ? 8 : 12;
    this.listProducts();
  } else {

    this.perPage = !this.layout ? 12 : 8;
    this.gridProducts();
  }
},
```

```html
<a class="list-icon" v-bind:class="{ active: layout == true }" v-on:click="layoutchange"></a>
<a class="grid-icon" v-bind:class="{ active: layout == false }" v-on:click="layoutchange"></a>

<ul v-if="layout == true">
  //code for product display
  <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage"></b-pagination>
</ul>

<ul v-if="layout == false">
  //code for product display
  <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage"></b-pagination>
  </ul
```

Basically i am trying to add the api call for the each page,(i have a api which need to call) for suppose if i click on pagination page no 1, i need to fire api, and same page 2 need to call api. Now i have a doubt, Now i am using the b-pagination (bootstrap-vue) are there any event to call for each page? like next previous or any event based. so with same name, i can call api using that.

I am using fr  grid and list view, For both i have pagination

Reference document  https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination

Comment: Can't you simply watch the `currentPage` data and make your call there?

Comment: @ThibautMaurice in currentPage if i make a call then will it be applicable for all pages. i mean page 1 page2 ...

Comment: I mean let's say you watch the `currentPage` data which I assume is a null value, set at X int when the component is mounted. Just make your call to your api in the watch function and pass `this.currentPage` as parameter in your query.

Comment: @ThibautMaurice if possible Can you please give some example code. It will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

If there is no event provided by `b-pagination` that you can use, in that specific usecase, you can just watch the `currentPage` property.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentPage: null,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    currentPage(newVal) {
      if(newVal) {
        // Call the api
        // Random api endpoint as example
        const endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'
        
        fetch(endpoint + newVal).then((res) => {
          console.log(res)
          // update corresponding data
        })
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Initialise currentPage to your route or 1 by default as example 
    this.currentPage = 1
  }
}
```